# Inserting HTML code snippets inside jspf file

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsp-fragments

I have a jspf file with java code inside. On one line, I have an if statement, that if excecuted, it will print one single Java line(a text string), but also some html content (a tooltip with a clickable image that expands an area). So the tooltip should only show up when the if statement is true, and also alongside the text String. When I import the jspf file in my main jsp file, the tooltip is visible all the time, but not in the place where my text string in the if statement is placed. The HTML content doesn´t seem to sync with the java code. is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Comment: Thank you very much for the info, I will do so!